# Ping of 2 VMs does not work

Tags: virtualization, ping

I installed 2 VMs on a VirtualBox. I used **Host Only NetWorking** and **NAT**.

1. VM 1: **Windows XP** with the following network settings:[image: VM 1: Windows XP. Networking Settings]
2. VM 2: **Ubuntu Server 11.04**. Network Settings:[image]

**when I ping a given VM from the other one it says: Uknown host 
Why can I not ping them each other ?**

Comment: What is the specific command you're running to ping one from the other?

Comment: ping 10.0.0.3 and from the other VM: ping 10.0.0.2

Comment: Are both VMs on the same host-only network? Or did you create a separate host-only network for each VM?

Comment: yes, they are on the same host only network, inside the same virtualbox

Comment: Well, "unknown host" is usually a DNS lookup failure. If you're pinging an IP address, DNS shouldn't be involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by setting `eth0` to the right way on Windows XP virtual machine.